# is there a reason why my merge sort does not work for array length 10

Tags: java, mergesort

I am setting up merge sort to sort my array. The goal is to sort an array with any length.

I have tried looking at the mergesort function, but i do not see anything wrong with it. the sort works for some array length be it odd or even but for array length such as length of 10, i get an over bound exception.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class MergeSort
{
 // Merge two sorted sub-arrays A[from .. mid] and A[mid + 1 .. to]
 public static void merge(int[] A, int[] temp, int from, int mid, int to)
 {
  int k = from, i = from, j = mid + 1;

  // loop till there are elements in the left and right runs
  while (i <= mid && j <= to) {
   if (A[i] < A[j]) {
    temp[k++] = A[i++];
   } else {
    temp[k++] = A[j++];
   }
  }

  // Copy remaining elements
  while (i <= mid) {
   temp[k++] = A[i++];
  }

  // Don't need to copy second half

  // copy back to the original array to reflect sorted order
  for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
   A[i] = temp[i];
  }
 }

 // Iteratively sort array A[low..high] using temporary array
 public static void mergesort(int[] A)
 {
  int low = 0;
  int high = A.length - 1;

  // sort array A[] using temporary array temp
  int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length);

  // divide the array into blocks of size m
  // m = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16...]
  for (int m = 1; m <= high - low; m = 2*m)
  {
   // for m = 1, i = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...
   // for m = 2, i = 0, 4, 8, 12...
   // for m = 4, i = 0, 8, 16...
   // ...
   for (int i = low; i < high; i += 2*m)
   {
    int from = i;
    int mid = i + m - 1;
    int to = Integer.min(i + 2 * m - 1, high);

    merge(A, temp, from, mid, to);
   }
  }
 }

 // Iterative Implementation of Mergesort algorithm
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int[] A = { 5, 7, -9, 3, -4, 2, 8, 8, 10, 11 };

  System.out.println("Original Array : " + Arrays.toString(A));
  mergesort(A);
  System.out.println("Modified Array : " + Arrays.toString(A));
 }
}
```

Comment: It is caused by A[i++] at line 19

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have already found that problem. how to I fix it tho.

Comment: This looks like a perfect time to use the debugger

Answer (score 1):

Your mid calculation is incorrect. You are sometimes setting it outside the range of the area.

This below change fixes the algorithm by preventing mid from going out of bounds, similar to how you did with preventing to from going out of bounds.

Change `int mid = i + m - 1;` to `int mid = Math.min(i + m - 1, A.length - 1);`

Explanation: As mentioned in your comment, the slices of area you are examining are increasing in size. So here is how your array is sorted, and when the out of bounds error occurs, and why it did not occur on sizes that are powers of 2:

```
             [ -9,  5,  7,  3, -4,  2,  8,  8, 10, 11 ]           Array size
 First pass:   []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []             1
     Second:   [    ]  [    ]  [    ]  [    ]  [    ]             2
      Third:   [            ]  [            ]  [       ERROR]     4
```

Comment: Thank you, It fixed the problem. if you have any additional input I will gladly accept. and I will work towards finding any other problem I find.

Comment: Updated my answer. I believe the approach is actually the best way to solve the problem and cap the number. The alternatives involve rewriting more code and in some cases slower anyways.

Comment: This approach does not reduce the number of calls made to the merge function, for a 10 number array the calls made are 11. Where as if you add the if conditional statement the number of calls gets reduces to 9. Check below solution for the same. Please do correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You're correct, this implementation of merge sort could be optimized. A break or conditional would stop it from unnecessarily re-sorting that section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fix:

Added an if statement for your mid not to cross the array bound

```
if(mid<high) {
            merge(A, temp, from, mid, to);
        }
```

Complete code:

```
// Merge two sorted sub-arrays A[from .. mid] and A[mid + 1 .. to]
public static void merge(int[] A, int[] temp, int from, int mid, int to)
{
    int k = from, i = from, j = mid + 1;

    // loop till there are elements in the left and right runs
    while (i <= mid && j <= to) {
        if (A[i] < A[j]) {
            temp[k++] = A[i++];
        } else {
            temp[k++] = A[j++];
        }
    }

    // Copy remaining elements
    while (i <= mid) {
        temp[k++] = A[i++];
    }

    // Don't need to copy second half

    // copy back to the original array to reflect sorted order
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        A[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

// Iteratively sort array A[low..high] using temporary array
public static void mergesort(int[] A)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = A.length - 1;

    // sort array A[] using temporary array temp
    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length);
    //System.out.println("temp Array : " + Arrays.toString(temp));

    // divide the array into blocks of size m
    // m = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16...]
    for (int m = 1; m <= high - low; m = 2*m)
    {
        // for m = 1, i = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...
        // for m = 2, i = 0, 4, 8, 12...
        // for m = 4, i = 0, 8, 16...
        // ...
        for (int i = low; i < high; i += 2*m)
        {
            int from = i;
            int mid = i + m - 1;
            int to = Integer.min(i + 2 * m - 1, high);

            if(mid<high) {
                merge(A, temp, from, mid, to);
            }

        }
    }
}

// Iterative Implementation of Mergesort algorithm
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] A = { 5, 7, -9, 3, -4, 2, 8, 8, 10, 11 };

    System.out.println("Original Array : " + Arrays.toString(A));
    mergesort(A);
    System.out.println("Modified Array : " + Arrays.toString(A));
}
```